# Unable to utilize sys args to modify variables

Tags: python, arguments

I am trying to change some variables, based on program arguments.

This is my code:

```
#initialize all scaling factors to 1
x_scale = 1
y_scale = 1
z_scale = 1

#the second argument is the axis to scale (1-3)
axis_Select = (sys.argv[2])
#the third argument is the scaling factor
scaling_Factor = (sys.argv[3])

if axis_Select == 1:
    x_scale = scaling_Factor
elif axis_Select == 2:
    y_scale = scaling_Factor
elif axis_Select == 3:
    z_scale = scaling_Factor
```

Then I invoke the program with:

```
python3 testScript.py /home/user/Desktop/file.extenstion 2 2
```

Then if i do a `print(y_scale)`, it is `1`, instead of `2` that it should be.

This works for other combinations as well, I just used the `y_scale` as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements of `sys.argv` are strings, you need to convert them to integers before comparing with integers.

```
#the second argument is the axis to scale (1-3)
axis_Select = int(sys.argv[2])
#the third argument is the scaling factor
scaling_Factor = int(sys.argv[3])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `argparse` for this

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument(
        "path", type=str, help="file path")
parser.add_argument(
        "axis_select",
        type=int)
parser.add_argument(
        "scaling_factor",
        type=int)

options = parser.parse_args()
```

`options` will contain provided values for `path`, `axis_select`, `scaling_factor`
accessible by `options.axis_select` etc

note that this will require 3 positional arguments - `path`, `axis_select`, `scaling_factor`
This will also convert it to proper type at the time

if you need to make those optional you can use

```py
parser.add_argument(
    "--path",
    default="/somedefaultpath",
)
```

In this case you'll need to specify it with `--path /something`

More details
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html